# Cygwin serial tty device for high-numbered COM ports

Tags: tty, cygwin, serial-port

My hardware enumerates as `COM125` on the device manager (CDC-ACM class). But, I can't find it under `/dev/tty*` listing. Does cygwin have a limitation on CDC-ACM class of com ports or numbers greater than 100? I have few other UARTs (emulated over USB) that enumerate as `COM10`–`COM20` range. These are listed as `/dev/ttyS9` and etc in cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does cygwin have a limitation on CDC-ACM class of com ports or numbers greater than 100?

Actually, the limit appears to be 64. There is a hard-coded table in [`winsup/cygwin/devices.cc`](https://cygwin.com/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob_plain;f=winsup/cygwin/devices.cc;hb=HEAD) within [the Cygwin source code](https://cygwin.com/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=tree) which has 64 entries for `/dev/ttyS*`. (It starts on line 732 in the current version.)

Since Windows itself copes with higher-numbered devices, this is likely to be an arbitrary choice (i.e. "Who would need more than 64 serial devices?") rather than some difficult-to-overcome limit in Cygwin or Windows. Therefore, I recommend that you check out a copy of the Cygwin sources, extend that table, and then [build your own `cygwin1.dll`](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.building-cygwin).

(I could do so myself, but since I lack a device that appears so far up there in `COM` space, I couldn't test the patch.)

If that succeeds, they will welcome your report on [the main mailing list](https://cygwin.com/lists.html).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I don't have this setup any more. Will make a point to file a patch next time.